# Android - Fix Position of Icon

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a two `RelativeLayouts` which each contains an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. On clicking on a `TextView`, the size of the `TextView` increases and the size of the other `Textview` decreases. However, the position of the `ImageView` also changes.I want the Image to be fixed irrespective of the size of the `textview`. What changes should be made?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/bb_bottom_bar_outer_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:background="@drawable/float_common"
             android:clickable="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_updatenow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_image_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
                android:background="@drawable/float_home_onclick"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/float_layout_offers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/float_offers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6"
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/float_text_offers"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:text="@string/offers"
                android:textColor="@color/text_mid_grey"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Try by setting your 2 RelativeLayout s android:layout_width as 0dp

Comment: @FebiMathew Its working Thanks
Could you please explain the logic though?

Comment: Answer added. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by setting your 2 RelativeLayout s android:layout_width as 0dp.

When Linearlayout contains many views inside and set layout_weight as 1 layout_height or layout_width = 0dp is used, in order to take equal space for both views.